# How to reset the height of iframe to 0 before adding content and getting height

Tags: jquery

I am using this to height of iframe conent:

```
$('iFrame').contents().height();
```

What i want is set the content to empty before adding content to it using url.
How can i do that. I tried this but is not working:

```
function loadiFrame(url) {

   $('iFrame').contents().empty();
   document.getElementById('iFrame').src = url;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the source to `about:blank`.

```
$("iframe").attr("src", "about:blank");
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/HBy5G/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function loadiFrame(url) {

   // clear the iFrame source
   $("#iFrame").attr("src", "");  
   // load the iFrame source
   $('#iFrame').attr("src", url);
}
```

You could also just chain the event to shave some time:

```
$('#iFrame').attr("src", "").attr("src", url);
```

I modified your url var setting as well...if you're using jQuery there's no need to use getElementById. Just use the jQuery selector approach with attr to get/set any attribute of a tag.